# Multi find beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I have a list of item like this: (the number of item lists can vary)

```
<h3>My title</h3>
<a href="http://myurl.com">http://myurl.com</a>
<span class="t">text</span>

<h3>My title</h3>
<a href="http://myurl.com">http://myurl.com</a>
<span class="t">text</span>

...
```

How with beautiful soup I could get all these data so I can put all of them is a list to have a result like this :
[{'title': h3, 'url': url, 'title': title}, {'title': h3, 'url': url, 'title': title}, ...] ?

thank you

Comment: Dictionary can't have duplicate keys with different values

Comment: Could you show the exact format of the list? Is it a nested list? Or just a plain list?

Comment: I edited my sample of data to be clearer

Comment: It would be helpful to know the website that you are pulling this information from, since you need a way to select/identify what you want to extract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over your HTML's contents like so (assuming that your data is held in `html_data`):

```
import bs4

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data)
my_list = []
for i in range(len(soup.body.contents), step=3):
    my_list.append({'title1': soup.body.contents[i], 'url': soup.body.contents[i+1], 'title2': soup.body.contents[i+2]})
```

This of course only works under the premise that your data resides on the same level and is not nested in any way. If it's not, then you should post a valid chunk of your test data and its structure.

Comment: So did this help you? Marking this as answered in such case would be constructive.